# What's the use of the accent mark on Regular Expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex, diacritics

I do not know why use the accent mark! Could you explain?
example:

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4})(?:\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4}))?\/?(.*)$/
```

Comment: you mean the carat? `^` or something else?

Comment: There is no accent mark. Do you mean the [Caret ^](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret)

Comment: Read up on regular expressions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to look in docs? Here you are: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 3):

If you mean `^` it's a position marker. It matches at the start of the string.

Correspondingly, `$` matches at the end of the string.

For example

```
^.
```

matches the first `a` in `archipelago`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it's there to mean *start of the string*.

for example /ran/ matches Iranian, but /^ran/ does not.

But in other circumstances, it means *not*. Read up on regex. There's a lot of good resources about.